# Make each Badge page a wiki

Tags: feature-request, badges

It would be nice to be able to put the information from the [`List of all badges with full descriptions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) post into each Badge page.  If the badge pages were wikis they could be updated by anyone.